# Как в <input type="file"/> отправить пустой файл

Tags: java, html, jquery

Есть код:

```
<input id="textMessage" type="text" placeholder="текст сообщения" autofocus>
<input type="file" id="imgMessage"/>
<button onclick="SendMessage()">отправить</button>
```

...

```
        var SendMessage = function () {
            var text = $("#textMessage").val();
            var img = $("#imgMessage")[0].files[0];
            var data = new FormData();

            if (text != "") {
                data.append("myText", text);
            } else {
                data.append("myText", "");
            }

            if (img != null) {
                data.append("myIMG", img);
            } else {
                data.append("myIMG", ???);
            }

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "<c:url value="/add/message"/>",
                data: data,
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                beforeSend: BeforeSendMessage,
                success: SuccessSendMessage,
                error: funkError
            })
        };
```

Возможен случай отправки сообщения без текста, только файл, тогда в коде jquery в if/else пишем `data.append("myText", "");`. Как сделать подобное для поля `<input type="file"`, в случае отправки только текста, без файла,
 т.е. что указать для атрибута `data.append("myIMG",`**???**`);` ,
null контроллер не принимает.

Код метода контроллера:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/add/message", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public void addMessage(HttpServletResponse response,
                           @RequestParam(value = "myText") String txt,
                           @RequestParam(value = "myIMG") MultipartFile file) {

        byte[] img = null;
        try {
            img = file.getBytes();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Message message = new Message();
        message.setText(txt);
        message.setImg(img);
        serviceMessage.add(message);
    }
```

Comment: Зачем вручную забивать FormData? Можно же просто `new FormData(form)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> @RequestParam(value = "myIMG") MultipartFile file
> ```

```
@RequestParam(value = "myIMG", required = false) MultipartFile file
```

Comment: это оно самое..

Comment: @user_Kyrt, если помогло, прими ответ нажатием на галочку слева.